# WML And Downloads

Tags: php, file-io, download, wap, wml

I'm now playing with *WML* and *WMLScript*, but I'm doing a site that will have some content to download(some txt, doc, bmp, mpg, avi and jpg files), but some of my friends(that never developed in this language, just used the technology on the beginning) said that it's impossible. Then here are my questions:

- It's possible?
- How to do it?

*Remember that I'm using PHP combined with WML.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If WML supports links to non-WML files and the typical WML browser can save files (remember that WML is mainly used on ancient mobile phones!) it should work.
It's not really PHP-related - for the client it doesn't matter if the data is generated by a php script or a static file.

Update: You can simple use link-title just like you would do in HTML.

Comment: Have you already tested this? You could try WinWap to see if it works. If you edit your answer after you test to show me the results of it, I will `acc` it. **:-)**